# Push changes to Git submodule into parent repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project A that has checked out a Git submodule S. I do some changes to the project configuration of S so that it can be built together with A. Now I commit these changes of S and I somehow want to push this commit in the repository of A.

When I don't and clone the repository of A, initalize and then update submodules, I get

```
$ git submodule update
fatal: reference is not a tree: f693b5a3a97390b027758ab38c550ef2a452ad90
Unable to checkout 'f693b5a3a97390b027758ab38c550ef2a452ad90' in submodule path 'my-submodule'
```

How can I commit changes to a submodule and include these changes in the parent repository?

Comment: May be it will helpful: http://brendancleary.com/2013/03/08/including-a-github-wiki-in-a-repository-as-a-submodule/

Comment: What I have done now is to fork the submodule's repository and push the changes to it. It would be kinda nice if these (very minor) changes could be contained in the parent repository. But maybe that could lead to issues later (if it were even possible)?